# A croissant shop has plain, cherry, chocolate, almond, apple, and broccoli croissants.

Tags: permutations, combinations

a) How many ways are there to choose a dozen croissants?

b) How many ways are there to choose three dozen croissants?

c) How many ways are there to choose two dozen croissants with at least two of each kind?

d) How many ways are there to choose two dozen croissants with no more than two broccoli croissants?

How I thought to do the problem:

a) $6^{12}$ because you can have repetition.

b) $6^{36}$ - same argument as a.

c) If you have to pick at least two of each kind, then you subtract a dozen croissants that you are allowed to choose because you have six different varieties. This gives $6^{12}$.

d) If you have two dozen croissants with no more than two broccoli croissants, then you can first take all the possibilities with zero broccoli croissants ($5^{26}$) + having one broccoli croissant ($5^{25}$) + having two broccoli croissants ($5^{24}$).

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: I would think that picking a cherry and an apple croissant is the same as picking an apple and cherry, but your answers don't account for this. This is a classic "stars-and-bars" type of problem.

Comment: Should you always assume that you have a stars and bars kind of problem whenever you have more spaces than you have items to choose from and order doesn't matter?

Comment: In your last answer, you should replace $[26,25,24]$ with $[24,23,22]$ respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Given Question is of the form "selecting indistinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes" and the formula is given by  $$\binom{n+r-1}{r}$$ where $n=$number of distinguishable boxes and $r=$number of indistinguishable object.

a) $$\binom{6+12-1}{12} =6188$$
b  $$\binom{6+36-1}{36} =749398$$
c) $$\binom{6+(24-12)-1}{12} =6188$$
d) $$\underbrace{\binom{5+(24-0)-1}{24}}_\text{zero broccoli croissants} + \underbrace{\binom{5+(24-1)-1}{23}}_\text{one broccoli croissants} +  \underbrace{\binom{5+(24-2)-1}{22}}_\text{two broccoli croissants} =20475+17550+14950=52975$$

Comment: I tried using LATEX to write the answer but as i am new i can't use it and hence could not write my answer in pure mathematical form.Please don't downvote it ,i am just requesting because my answer is correct and the member seeing the downvote may not accept this answer as correct ..hope u understand...@Fabian

Comment: I suspect that the reason for the downvote is that you supplied answers to the questions without explaining your reasoning (other than giving a formula to use).